# Meaning of sentences in form "Nor...,as"

Tags: meaning-in-context, ambiguity

What does a sentence mean in the form of "Nor..., as"?

For example, consider the following sentence:

> The usage of the material is not limited by its appearance. **Nor** was the usage limited, **as** some scholars insist, to the modern period.

Although what the sentence is trying to convey is clear: the usage of the material is not limited by both its appearance and the modern period, I am having difficulty understanding the role of the scholars.

Do the scholars insist that the usage was limited to the modern period (which means the scholars are criticized by the author), or do they insists the usage was not limited to the modern period (which means the author concurs with the scholars)?

Comment: It is saying that some scholars insist the usage was limited to the modern period, but that the writer disagrees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not some sort of *nor .. as* construction, analogous to *neither .. nor* or *more .. than*—there is no such construction. The clause introduced by *as* is a supplement, a parenthetical remark which qualifies the positive (unnegated) sense of the main clause; it could be bracketed with parentheses or dashes, or moved, or omitted without changing the sense of the main clause, which is

> Nor was the usage limited (as some scholars insist) to the modern period.
>   Nor was the usage limited to the modern period, as some scholars insist.
>   Nor was the usage limited to the modern period.

You may paraphrase:

> The usage was not limited to the modern period, even though some scholars insist that it was.